Where can I find the body of the function pointed to by the function pointer of cfg_hooks in gcc source code？
In gcc cfghooks.cc
void
predict_edge (edge e, enum br_predictor predictor, int probability)
{
  if (!cfg_hooks->predict_edge)
    internal_error ("%s does not support predict_edge", cfg_hooks->name);

  cfg_hooks->predict_edge (e, predictor, probability);
}

I find this line cfg_hooks->predict_edge (e, predictor, probability);,
and the predict_edge is a function pointer defined in cfghooks.h
  /* Predict edge E using PREDICTOR to given PROBABILITY.  */
  void (*predict_edge) (edge e, enum br_predictor predictor, int probability);

I can't find which function this pointer point to...

I wanna know where can I find this function body. Thanks for helping.

There are two implementations for two different IRs, rtl_predict_edge in gcc/cfgrtl.cc and gimple_predict_edge in gcc/predict.cc.

yes, I find both of them in gcc/predict.cc. Their arugments list looks consistent with the parameters passed in when cfg_hooks calls them by predict_edge.
But when is this function pointer predict_edge initialized?
